# Is it common practice to redirect for skipping www?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, http, web

I want to advertize my website as mydomain.com. For me it looks nicer than www.mydomain.com. Is it a common practice to trim this `www.` part with redirection? Somebody would go to `www.mydomain.com/books` and I would redirect him to `mydomain.com/books`. Are there any potential traps behind this idea?

Another reason is making third party callback URLs simple. For now, I need to declare both `mydomain.com/oauth/google` and `www.mydomain.com/oauth/google` as my redirect URLs, because Google considers them different. It's not a huge deal, but something extra to take into account.

If it's safe to trim `www.`, how can that be achieved? I'm using PHP on Apache. My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do it with Apache (either vHost config or .htaccess).

Comment: `Is it common practice to redirect for skipping www?`[This might answer your question](http://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www) I noticed all the big sites at some point when they get big start using www. Instagram for one did not at first now it does exclusively. Maybe also because Facebook does. But so does snapchat and many other large sites. I've recently started enforcing www as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Should you use www?

You should normalize on either www.example.com or example.com, which you choose is mostly up to your preference.  There are varying opinions on which is correct or which should be used.

[no-www.org](http://no-www.org) advocates that it is redundant to use the www subdomain as using the http protocol implies the web.

> By default, all popular Web browsers assume the HTTP protocol. In doing so, the software prepends the 'http://' onto the requested URL and automatically connect to the HTTP server on port 80. Why then do many servers require their websites to communicate through the www subdomain? Mail servers do not require you to send emails to recipient@mail.domain.com. Likewise, web servers should allow access to their pages though the main domain unless a particular subdomain is required.

[yes-www.org](http://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/) on the other hand advocates using the www subdomain because it allows your website to be more flexiable. By using the www subdomain you can use things like CDN's / cloud hosting easier by using a CNAME in your dns records.

> When using a provider such as Heroku or Akamai to host your web site, the provider wants to be able to update DNS records in case it needs to redirect traffic from a failing server to a healthy server. This is set up using DNS CNAME records, and the naked domain cannot have a CNAME record.

It can also help prevent unnecessary cookie traffic when you have static assets hosted on another domain.

> One common web site optimization is to serve static content from a subdomain, such as static.example.com. If you are using www, then this is no problem; your site’s cookies won’t be sent to the static subdomain (unless you explicitly set them up to do so).

## Once you've decided

You'll want to redirect all traffic to which ever version you end up using.  With apache this can be done using mod_rewrite as shown in other answers:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you are able to edit the main apache configuration, another option is to setup two Virtual Hosts where one just redirects to the other.  I do this for my site and it's worked well.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    #The rest of your configuration
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I prefer to do it in .htaccess to keep it project-wise. I updated my question and pasted my current .htaccess. Could you take a look if I could use this rule along with some others in my file? I'm already redirecting if there's trailing slash, so maybe I could include both of those conditions in one rule?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer from the SEO perspective.

As [SEO MOZ](http://moz.com) suggests in their awesome [Beginner's Guide to SEO](https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo):

> Often, two or more copies of the exact same content appear on
>   your website under different URLs. For example, the following
>   URLs can all refer to a single homepage:
>
> - http://www.example.com/
> - http://www.example.com/default.asp
> - http://example.com/
> - http://example.com/default.asp
> - http://Example.com/Default.asp
>
> To search engines, these appear as five separate pages. Because
>   the content is identical on each page, this can cause the search
>   engines to devalue the content and its potential rankings.

From this we may conclude, that it does not matter if you set your page with or without `www.`. But it is a good idea to redirect with HTTP code `301` to one "unified" domain. Apache 2 supports `.htaccess` settings for this purposes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your insightful SEO perspective :) Could you take a look at my updated question? I included my current .htaccess. Maybe this rule can be simplified to work along with my trailing slashes rule?

Comment: you don't have to redirect trailing slashes, it's okay if you rewrite them with `mod_rewrite` in apache. There's an answer on how to do that here on SO - search for it or open a new question (but rather search for it :))

Comment: Those trailing slashes are trimmed by Laravel framework actually. it's default .htaccess in this framework.

Answer (score 0):

You do this with a `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use .htaccess you can redirect in a simple way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```